# Problem with Netway/Maxxter Wireless keyboard and mouse

Tags: 18.04, wireless, keyboard, mouse

I'm having some issues trying to get work a combo mouse/keyboard wireless device. The mouse works properly, however the keyboard doesn't work. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

The model is a Netway NW780, but it seems to be manufactured from Maxxter.

The tricky thing is that is working properly in the same computer with Centos 7. If I connect the wireless combo to another computer with Ubuntu 18.04, the same problem occurs.

I've tried to remove and add again the usbhid module, but the problem persist:

`sudo modprobe -r usbhid`

`sudo modprobe usbhid`

I post the output from hwinfo:

1.-) Keyboard:

> 57: USB 00.1: 10800 Keyboard
>     [Created at usb.122]
>     Unique ID: x0O1.dFICFZCwlN0
>     Parent ID: BSFT.BwiLSoUZ6N9
>     SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/usb7/7-3/7-3:1.1
>     SysFS BusID: 7-3:1.1
>     Hardware Class: keyboard
>     Model: "Maxxter Wireless Receiver"
>     Hotplug: USB
>     Vendor: usb 0x248a "Maxxter"
>     Device: usb 0x8367 "Wireless Receiver"
>     Revision: "1.00"
>     Driver: "usbhid"
>     Driver Modules: "usbhid"
>     Device File: /dev/input/event5
>     Device Files: /dev/input/event5, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Telink_Wireless_Receiver-if01-event-kbd, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:16.0-usb-0:3:1.1-event-kbd
>     Device Number: char 13:69
>     Speed: 12 Mbps
>     Module Alias: "usb:v248Ap8367d0100dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip01in01"
>     Driver Info #0:
>       XkbRules: xfree86
>       XkbModel: pc104
>     Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
>     Attached to: #55 (Hub)

2.-) Mouse:

> 53: USB 00.0: 10503 USB Mouse
>     [Created at usb.122]
>     Unique ID: Ur7z.M_nrmne0cTF
>     Parent ID: BSFT.BwiLSoUZ6N9
>     SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/usb7/7-3/7-3:1.0
>     SysFS BusID: 7-3:1.0
>     Hardware Class: mouse
>     Model: "Maxxter Wireless Receiver"
>     Hotplug: USB
>     Vendor: usb 0x248a "Maxxter"
>     Device: usb 0x8367 "Wireless Receiver"
>     Revision: "1.00"
>     Compatible to: int 0x0210 0x0025
>     Driver: "usbhid"
>     Driver Modules: "usbhid"
>     Device File: /dev/input/mice (/dev/input/mouse0)
>     Device Files: /dev/input/mice, /dev/input/mouse0, /dev/input/event2, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Telink_Wireless_Receiver-event-mouse, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:16.0-usb-0:3:1.0-event-mouse, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Telink_Wireless_Receiver-mouse, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:16.0-usb-0:3:1.0-mouse
>     Device Number: char 13:63 (char 13:32)
>     Speed: 12 Mbps
>     Module Alias: "usb:v248Ap8367d0100dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip02in00"
>     Driver Info #0:
>       Buttons: 5
>       Wheels: 2
>       XFree86 Protocol: explorerps/2
>       GPM Protocol: exps2
>     Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
>     Attached to: #55 (Hub)

3.-) Hub from is attached (see the previous line)

> 55: USB 00.0: 10a00 Hub
>     [Created at usb.122]
>     Unique ID: BSFT.BwiLSoUZ6N9
>     Parent ID: WnlC.BDXXLZhMRx2
>     SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/usb7/7-0:1.0
>     SysFS BusID: 7-0:1.0
>     Hardware Class: hub
>     Model: "Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub"
>     Hotplug: USB
>     Vendor: usb 0x1d6b "Linux Foundation"
>     Device: usb 0x0001 "1.1 root hub"
>     Revision: "5.00"
>     Serial ID: "0000:00:16.0"
>     Driver: "hub"
>     Driver Modules: "usbcore"
>     Speed: 12 Mbps
>     Module Alias: "usb:v1D6Bp0001d0500dc09dsc00dp00ic09isc00ip00in00"
>     Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
>     Attached to: #26 (USB Controller)

4.- USB Controller: (#26)

> 26: PCI 16.0: 0c03 USB Controller (OHCI)
>     [Created at pci.378]
>     Unique ID: WnlC.BDXXLZhMRx2
>     SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0
>     SysFS BusID: 0000:00:16.0
>     Hardware Class: usb controller
>     Model: "ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller"
>     Vendor: pci 0x1002 "ATI Technologies Inc"
>     Device: pci 0x4397 "SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller"
>     SubVendor: pci 0x1002 "ATI Technologies Inc"
>     SubDevice: pci 0x4397 
>     Driver: "ohci-pci"
>     Memory Range: 0xfe205000-0xfe205fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
>     IRQ: 22 (3574 events)
>     Module Alias: "pci:v00001002d00004397sv00001002sd00004397bc0Csc03i10"
>     Driver Info #0:
>       Driver Status: ohci-hcd is not active
>       Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe ohci-hcd"
>     Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown

Anyone could help?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.